# Swing draws only after resizing

Tags: java, swing

Program should draw the line twice longer after clicking the button, but it only does that after clicking AND THEN resizing the window. I don't know what is happening, i thought this is gonna be easy.

Could you tell me how can I fix it?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Stack;

class MyButtonPanel extends JPanel {

public static final int HEIGHT = 800;
public static final int WIDTH = 800;
private JButton greenButton;
private JPanel buttonPanel;
Stack<Point> points;
int X = 25;
int Y = 25;

public MyButtonPanel() {
    greenButton = new GreenButton();
    points = new Stack<Point>();

    buttonPanel = this;

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    add(greenButton);

}

class GreenButton extends JButton implements ActionListener
{
    GreenButton() {
        super("LongerLine");
        addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //points.push(new Point(0,0));
        X = 2 * X;
        Y = 2 * Y;
        validate();
    }

}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    //g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    //g2d.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    //drawLines(g2d);
    Line2D lin = new Line2D.Double(0,0, X, Y);
    g2d.draw(lin);
}

private void drawLines(Graphics2D g2d) {
    //Line2D lin = new Line2D.Float(100, 100, 250, 260);
    //g2d.draw(lin);
    double x1, y1, x2, y2;
    /*
    for(Point point: points) {
        x1 = (double) point.getX();
        y1 = (double) point.getY();
        Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(x1,y1,200,200);
        g2d.draw(line);
    }
    */
}




}

public class MyActionFrame extends JFrame {

public MyActionFrame() {
    super("Test akcji");

    JPanel buttonPanel = new MyButtonPanel();
    add(buttonPanel);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    //setResizable(false);
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MyActionFrame();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This `validate();`, or better `revalidate();` is called when a container's layout needs to be re-done, often when components are added or removed, and is not what you're doing or desiring. Instead you want to call `repaint()` which suggests that the component be painted.

Comment: I have changed validate() to repaint() and it behaves still the same.

Comment: @TomaszŻuchowski, You need to repaint the panel, not the button. Your code is not structured properly. There is no need to extend JButton.  The X/Y variables are part of the panel and the ActionListener should be defined in the panel as well. Then when you invoke repaint() when the listener is invoked the repaint() will be for the panel, not the button

Comment: @camickr: make that an answer please as I didn't catch that.